# preg_replace deleting instead of replacing

Tags: php, regex, file, preg-replace

This is probably some dumb regex error or something, but here goes:

I'm looping with PHP through a list of files and replacing parts of their text, partially with `str_replace` and partially with `preg_replace`. I have an array of arrays of items to be replaced and their replacements (or replacement schemas). However, for only one of the regex replacements, it is outright deleting all of the instances of the text to be replaced except the last, which it properly replaces.

Here is my array of regexes. Only the last element is having this issue; the others replace in all instances just fine.

```
// List of offending links or scripts that have variable values that need regexes to be properly removed
$offenders_regex = array(
    array( '~<a href="viewforum\.php\?id=(.*)">(.*)</a>~', '$2' ), // Replace links to certain sections with just the name of that section
    array( '~<a href="viewtopic\.php\?pid=(.*)#p(.*)">~', '<a href="#p$1">' ), // Replace links to posts with same-page anchors
    array( '~<a href="search\.php\?action=show_user\&user_id=(.*)">Posts</a>~', 'Posts' ), // Remove link to all posts by a user
    array( '~<a href="viewtopic\.php\?id=(.*)\&amp;p=(.*)">(.*)</a>~', '<a href="page-$2.html">$3</a>' ), // Replace links to other pages of a topic with the proper link
);
```

Here is the code I'm using to loop through the files:

```
foreach( $list as $file ){
    $file_text = preg_replace( '~\R~u', "\r\n", stripslashes( file_get_contents( $file ) ) );
    if ($file_text!=FALSE) {
        foreach( $offenders_replace as $cur_replace ){
            $file_text = str_replace( $cur_replace[0], $cur_replace[1], $file_text );
        }
        foreach( $offenders_regex as $cur_regex ){
            $file_text = preg_replace( $cur_regex[0], $cur_regex[1], $file_text, -1, $count );
        }
        $e = file_put_contents( $file, $file_text );
        if ($e == FALSE){
            echo "Unable to write to " . $file . ".<br/>";
        }
        else echo "Wrote successfully to " . $file . ".<br/>";
    }
    else {
        if (!is_dir($file)) echo "Unable to write to " . $file . ".<br/>";
    }
}
```

The text that the regex is supposed to run on and replace is:

```
<p class="pagelink conl">Pages: <strong>1</strong>&nbsp;<a href="viewtopic.php?id=100290&amp;p=2">2</a>&nbsp;<a href="viewtopic.php?id=100290&amp;p=3">3</a></p>
```

Comment: i think you need the `U (PCRE_UNGREEDY)` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just modified your regex:

- I replaced these "mean" greedy patterns `.*` with ungreedy ones `.*?` or even better using patterns like `[^&]*` meaning: Get everything until &

  ```
  ~<a href="viewtopic\.php\?id=([^&]*)\&amp;p=([^"]*)">([^<]*)</a>~
  ```

[`Working DEMO`](http://regex101.com/r/dI7dP7)

Comment: Why do you want to escape the slash? It is not used as delimiter.

Comment: @M42: ow, you're right... I've got an error on the tester I use because he uses it as delimiter... Answer edited :)